# How to create DialogFragment layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to programmatically create a DialogFragment layout, but I don't know how to proceed. I cannot use xml layout because the DialogFragment will be a part of closed-source JAR file.

Normal Dialogs accept an Activity in their constructor, so it is then possible to instantiate a new Layout like this: `layout = new LinearLayout(this);`. DialogFragments, on the other hand, do not usually take the Activity as a parameter, so I don't know how to perform this first step.

1. How should I create the layout?
2. Is it OK to ask for an Activity in the constructor?
3. Is creating a layout of DialogFragment any different from creating a layout of normal Dialog?
   I will be grateful for any other advice regarding manual DialogFragment design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I create the layout?

How ever you want it to look. If you can't/don't want to use a layout file that you inflate and return from the `onCreateView` method you'll have to build the entire view hierarchy of your new dialog in code.

> Is it OK to ask for an Activity in the constructor?

There is no need for this, the `Fragment` will get a reference to an `Activity`, you'll have a reference to that context by using `getActivity()`.

> Is creating a layout of DialogFragment any different from creating a
>   layout of normal Dialog? I will be grateful for any other advice
>   regarding manual DialogFragment design.

No, it's not different. The [documentation for the `DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) has a great example on how to build a custom `DialogFragment`, you should check it out.